# Can we use BT Donate on CIVICRM?

Tags: gift-aid-extension

We are a newly formed not for profit organisation. On our current website people donate via BT MYDONATE which goes to our account with a charity called Prism the Gift fund.  Is it possible to use the same link to BT DONATE on our new website with CIVICRM?

Comment: can you explain what 'outcome' you are looking to get? i expect the simple answer is 'yes you can put a link' but 'no it won't save data in civicrm'

Comment: BT MY Donate is a UK giving portal, adding the same function on your new site would work but my advice would be to use Stripe or some other payment gateway as you'll capture the donors details into CiviCRM this way and start to see some of the benefits of having an integrated system.